# Is it possible to submit a <h:commandlink> action without closing a modalpanel?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, modal-dialog

I have the following  inside a richfaces modalpanel:

```
<ui:repeat id="al11" var="albumslistvalue1" value="#{AlbumDetailBean.getAlbumImagesList()}"
varStatus="albumslistvalue1Index">
  <rich:modalPanel id="panel#{albumslistvalue1Index}" width="850" height="560">
    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:panelGroup>
        <h:outputText value="Fotos"/>
      </h:panelGroup>
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="controls">
      <h:panelGroup>
        <h:graphicImage value="/img/modal/close.png" styleClass="hidelink" id="hidelink"/>
        <rich:componentControl for="panel" attachTo="hidelink" operation="hide"
        event="onclick" />
      </h:panelGroup>
    </f:facet>
    <!-- content-->
    <center>
      <h:graphicImage value="img/cart/prior16.png" />
      <h:graphicImage value="albums/#{albumslistvalue1.albumImageId}/med_#{albumslistvalue1.albumimagename}"/>
      <h:graphicImage value="img/cart/next16.png" />
      <h:commandLink id="comp" action="#{AlbumDetailBean.getCartAlbums()}">
        <div>
          <h:outputText value="Comprar" />
          <f:param name="albumproductid" value="#{albumslistvalue1.id}" />
        </div>
      </h:commandLink>
    </center>
  </rich:modalPanel>
  <h:outputLink value="#" id="link">
    <!-- Show Modal Panel -->
    <h:graphicImage id="image" url="albums/#{albumslistvalue1.albumImageId}/mini_#{albumslistvalue1.albumimagename}"
    width="100px" height="auto" />
    <rich:componentControl for="panel#{albumslistvalue1Index}" attachTo="link"
    operation="show" event="onclick" />
  </h:outputLink>
</ui:repeat>
```

and getCartAlbums() method:

```
public List getCartAlbums() {
  boolean status = false;
  AlbumImpl bean1 = new AlbumImpl();

  String productidval = ((HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()).getParameter("albumproductid");

  AlbumDetailBean albums = (AlbumDetailBean) bean1.bo_getAlbumImageDetails(productidval);

  if(albums != null) {

    cartAlbumDetails.add(albums);
    setId(albums.getId());
    setAlbumname(albums.getAlbumname());
    setSchoolId(albums.getSchoolId());
    setAlbumImageId(albums.getAlbumImageId());
    setAlbumimagename(albums.getAlbumimagename());
    // setAlbumimage(albums.getAlbumimage());
    setListPrice(albums.getListPrice());
    setAvailableQty(albums.getAvailableQty());
    setTotalAmount(albums.getTotalAmount());
    setProductcode(albums.getProductcode());
    setListpricevalue(albums.getListpricevalue());
    setProductsize(albums.getProductsize());
    setQtyvalue(albums.getQtyvalue());
    setTotalpricevalue(albums.getTotalpricevalue());
    setProductid(albums.getProductid());
    setShipPrice(albums.getShipPrice());
  }
  return cartAlbumDetails;
}
```

I'm using someone else's code, so i didn't write the getCartAlbums() method, but it basically add the select image to the cart, it's working, the images are added to the cart correctly, but the modalpanel still closes

Comment: try changing the return value of `getCartAlbums` to null or making it a void method

Comment: Please, post the code of the modal panel and of the `getCartAlbums()` method too, so that we can help better.

Comment: making it void and/or returning didn't help @Daniel
just posted the codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're using JSF 1/RF3? getCartAlbums() is returning a list, is this right? My JSF 1 knowledge is from the distant past but it doesn't look right.

However, the problem is that the h:commandLink is doing a full page submit, a POST request which reloads the page with the results of the postback (the response to the POST request). So after the button is pushed you see the screen redraw and what you're seeing is the page in the same state (albeit with updated values) as it was in when you first loaded it, which is without a modalPanel.

To remedy the problem you want to use a4j:commandLink to perform an ajax partial submit. I'm not sure if RF3 has execute= and render= attributes on the a4j:commandLink component or whether you have to use a4j:support as a child component, but I'm sure you can find out. You use execute= to specify which components values are submitted in the body of the ajax POST request, and render= to specify which components are updated after the postback is received.

Comment: In RF 3 you have `process` instead of `execute` and `reRender` instead of `render`. Also, the better advice to handle this would be to set the Managed Bean with request scope and add the `@KeepAlive` annotation at the beginning of the managed bean class definition.

Comment: I'm using <a4j:commandLink> now, and realized that those lines were on my pages.xml:
<navigation from-action="#{AlbumDetailBean.getCartAlbums()}">
  <redirect view-id="/ViewAlbumImages.xhtml"/>
</navigation>

so, the page was being redirected to itself everytime the action getCartAlbums() was executed, i removed this and everything became only one little problem: after the action is executed, the page rest of the page doesn't get "reRendered"

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Luiggi, I was struggling to remember!

Comment: Does anyone know why the i can't reRender a div outside the modalpanel ?

Comment: The most likely reason is that it's in a different naming container (i.e. a form). Can you check the page source or use your browser developer tools to check the client id. You may need to use a construct such as reRender="form2:myid".

Comment: Yes Oversteer, i was using reRender="formgeral:cart2" the reason it wasn't working is :
"Most common problem with using reRender is pointing it to the component that has a "rendered" attribute. ... As an alternative, you can wrap the component with <a4j:outputPanel> layout="none" " - Taken from http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html - 5.6.1. Re-Rendering.

I tried with <a4j:outputPanel> and with no "rendered" and it worked, thanks to all who helped